# Is there anyway to replace a Web Control with an HTML template string?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-controls

I'm trying to use template strings to render reusable components in a asp.net web forms app. I can get it to work the way I want to, the only problem is that I can't seem to get rid of the `ContentPlaceHolder` parent.

I tried using `WebControl.InnerHtml = "<h1>my custom template</h1>"`, but this obviously only adds children to the node and it doesn't get rid of it. Something like `WebControl.OuterHtml` would fix my problem completely but that doesn't seem to exist. Is this possible to do at all?

Comment: Content template place holder ONLY exists if using master page. A master page simple means all content for your existing page will be placed inside of the content template and you should not care one tiny bit (who cares!!!). All content thus will be placed inside of that content template including any markup and that includes inserting a UC into that page. There is ZERO reason why you should care about content template. All of your page markup goes in that content template including that of UC's. Place that UC into a non master page, and there will be no content template.